# Angular HttpClient request with debounceTime does not wait for dueTime

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to implement a debounceTime for a http request that occurs as a user is filtering a table column:

```
this.myService.getData()
  .pipe(debounceTime(1000), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe((res) => {
    // Do work
  });
```

But it's not waiting for the dueTime of 1000ms.

I must have made an error because it behaves exactly the same when I remove all the pipes, but where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange thing you are doing here :).  Here you telling to wait 1s after you receive the response of your async call. I think this is not what you want to do. You should do in your component.

html :

```
<input [formControl]="autoCompletFormControl" type="text" />
```

ts :

```
   autoCompletFormControl = new FormControl();

   this.autoCompletFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe( (value) => {
         this.service.getData(value).subscribe( (value) => {
           this.values = values;
         });
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, your right! But is it at all possible to call a method on input change with my solution and get the same result?

Comment: personnaly I always use  with formControl since you can subscribe to an Observable and have great control with rxjs pipe. In AngularJS (angular 1) they was a delay on model-options, but not anymore in Angular. I can't see any other solution yet

Answer (score 1):

In case you cannot use debounceTime with an observable before service call (like valueChanges), you can do it also this way:

```
timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(() => this.service.getData(value)))
           .subscribe(values => this.values = values);
```

Comment: it's not debouncing, it's just delaying, no? I think the right way would be to make a new subject, pipe and debounce it and then in the subscribe make the myService.getData().subscribe... + unsubscribe. Or use the debounce function from the loadash package.